# Invoking Cloud Function/Cloud Run with default credentials

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-authentication, google-cloud-run

I need to call other cloud functions/cloud run services from my cloud function. I would like to be authenticated if possible so to that effect I have been looking into how to create an `AuthorizedSession` using the credentials I get back from `google.auth.default`. My current code looks like so:

```
credentials, _ = google.auth.default(scopes=[
   SERVICE_A_URL,
   SERVICE_B_URL,
   SERVICE_C_URL,
])
return AuthorizedSession(credentials)
```

When running this I get the following:

```
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('No access token in response.', {'id_token': '[ID_TOKEN]'})
```

Does anyone know how to get the `AuthorizedSession` to accept my credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Authorized session works well with Google Cloud APIs which expect an access token. In the case of Cloud Functions and Cloud Run (and also App Engine behind IAP) you need to provide an identity token.

So, you can't with authorized session, you need to generate and ID token with the correct audience and then to add it in the authorization header of your request.

```
 credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"])
 
 credentials.with_target_audience("SERVICE_A_URL")

 from google.auth.transport import requests
 credentials.refresh(requests.Request())
 print(credentials.token)

 request.get("SERVICE_A_URL+Parameters", headers={'Authorization': 'bearer {}'.format(credentials.token)})
```

Comment: Running this code results in: `AttributeError: 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'with_target_audience'`

Comment: Changing the code to this seems to do the trick though, thanks for the help!

```def create_google_token(url: str) -> str:
    """Create an authorised token for calling GCP instances."""
    auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, url)
    return id_token```

Then use that id_token in a request with a header like `Authorization: Bearer {id_token}`

Comment: Yes you can also use fecth_id!!